# How do I make a Github project show up on two profiles?

Tags: git, github

A friend and I are working on a project on Github and we want it to be on both of our profiles for resumes and stuff. Is this possible?

Comment: Belongs on webapps.stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this project to be considered as one project, one of you must create it, and other one should fork it (not really necessary). Both of you should have full rights on the original repo, so both can directly access it.

Use the README page (the home page of the project) to give due credits to both of you. This thing would work for your resumes and stuff.

I don't think it is possible to have same project on two profiles, and still have them considered as one. Although you can create them individually, but managing both of them may be a bit more of a headache than its worth.

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate, but oh well!

Answer (score 1):

You can also setup an organization and create the repository in this organization. Both of your profiles will show that you contribute to the organization's repository and therefor link to the repository.